# Passing props to useState React

Tags: reactjs, redux, state, react-hooks

I' am trying to use props coming from redux as a starting point for rendering my state-full component like this:

```
const MyComp = (props) => {

    const initState = {
        newAttribs: [...props.attribs]
        };

    const [state, setState] = useState(initState)
    console.log(state)

};

const mapStateToProps = (fromRedux) => {...};
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {...};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(React.memo(MyComp));
```

But if I `console.log(state)` it shows empty array for `newAttribs` even though in `initState newAttribs` are there.

Can someone shed some light on how to do this properly?
Thanks.

EDIT:

I've made an error while posting code snippet, I updated it now.
`const mapStateToProps` and `const mapDispatchToProps` obviously have to be outside of the component scope and they are.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are three things that you need to take care of

1. The argument to useState is only used once during initial load and state won't update when props change
2. `mapStateToProps` and `mapDispatchToProps` should be defined outside of the component scope
3. When `props.attribs` changes you need to update your component state which you can do using `useEffect`

Example

```
const MyComp = (props) => {

    const initState = {
        newAttribs: [...props.attribs]
    };

    const [state, setState] = useState(initState)

    useEffect (() => { 
          setState({ ...state, newAttribs: [...props.attribs] }) 
    }, [props.attribs])
    console.log(state)


};

const mapStateToProps = (fromRedux) => {...};
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {...};
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(React.memo(MyComp));
```

If the data from redux store is available before initial mount you will see it in `console.log`

Comment: Thank you very much. That was helpful and now rather obvious. I solved my problem by:                                
 ```useEffect (() => {
        setState({
            ...state,
            newAttribs: [...props.attribs],
        })
            },[props.attribs])```

Comment: Glad to have helped.

Comment: If you agree that this should be done with ```useEffect``` add my code from comment to your answer and I will accept it. In this form, I think, answer is not complete because it doesn't include solution to the problem.

Comment: Updated the answer. And yes useEffect needs to be used if you wish to update state  based on prop change